# Principles of grouping neurons

Tags: neuroscience, methodology, cognitive-modeling, neuroanatomy

This is an overview question. I wonder which principles of grouping neurons into higher units are there, and which principles I have overseen.

- **neurotransmitter systems**: all neurons that release or react on a given (class or set of) neurotransmitters
- **functional systems**: all neurons (and groups of neurons) that are involved in performing a given task or function
- **regions**: all neurons in a given 3-dimensional volume of the brain, e.g. a voxel
- **nuclei** etc: a group of nearby neurons which somehow belong to each other (morphologically or synaptically, possibly encapsulated by some "membrane")
- **clusters**: a group of neurons (nearby or not) that are strongly interconnected by synapses
- **independent sets**: of a [multipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_graph) subgraph of the [brain network](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6136126/)
- groups defined **by other graph-theoretical measures**
- **pathways**: a somehow distinguished (e.g. shortest) synaptical route from neuron (group) A to neuron (group) B
- **cortical layers**
- **cortical columns**

To make my question specific and not too broad, let me just ask the following:

> **Which principles of grouping neurons is missing in the list above?**

(There should be not so many.)

For each classified group of neurons some numbers will be interesting to know:

- How many neurons do they typically comprise?
- How many groups of the same kind are there?
- How strongly do they overlap?

Answer (score 1):

In anatomy/physiology, there are 2 major categorizations of the nervous system:

1. **Central nervous system** (brain + spinal cord) and **peripheral nervous system** (all other neural structures)
2. **Somatic nervous system,** which controls skeletal muscles and skin, and and **autonomic n. system,** which controls internal organs, blood vessels and glands and is further divided to **sympathetic** and **parasympathetic system.** Both the somatic and autonomic system have **motor** neurons that control muscles and **sensory** neurons that convey sensory signals.

[image]

Image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nervous_system), creative commons license

Neurons can be further categorized by [neurotransmitters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotransmitter) involved (dopamine system, acetylcholine system, etc.), and by various anatomical and functional subsystems.

Examples of anatomical and functional structures formed by neurons:

- **Cortical areas** (functional areas of the brain cortex) ([Lumen](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-ap/chapter/functional-systems-of-the-cerebral-cortex/))
- **Main parts of the brain:** cerebrum, cerebellum and brainstem, some of which can be further divided into hemispheres, lobes and folds
- **Deep structures of the brain:** thalamus, hypotalamus, hypocampus, amygdala, corpus callosum, limbic system, pituitary gland, pineal gland, and structures collectivelly called **basal ganglia,** which include the caudate, putamen, and globus pallidus in the cerebrum, the substantia nigra in the midbrain, and the subthalamic nucleus in the diencephalon ([Mayfield Clinic](https://mayfieldclinic.com/pe-anatbrain.htm)).
- **Areas containing either neuron cell bodies or axons:** gray matter (cell bodies) and white matter (axons) of the brain and spinal cord ([Indiana.edu](http://www.indiana.edu/~p1013447/dictionary/greywhit.htm))
- **Histological areas of the brain:** layers and columns ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerebral_cortex))
- **Nuclei** of the cranial nerves ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranial_nerve_nucleus))
- **Centers** (cardiovascular center, reflex center for cough, vomiting, etc.) in medulla oblongata ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medulla_oblongata))
- **Corticospinal tracts** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corticospinal_tract))
- **Pathways** - the term is usually used for cranial nerves: visual pathway, auditory pathway, etc.
- **Ganglia** - anatomical structures containing neuron body cells in the peripheral nervous system ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganglion))
- **Nerve plexuses** - branching networks of intersecting nerves ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_plexus))
- **Reflex arcs** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex_arc))